# Linker Error when adding card.io SDK to iOS project

Tags: ios, card.io

I followed the instructions and here is the error:

```
duplicate symbol _kGPUImageGaussianBlurFragmentShaderString in:
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUTransformFilter.o)
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUGaussianBlurFilter.o)
duplicate symbol _kGPUImageGaussianBlurVertexShaderString in:
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUTransformFilter.o)
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUGaussianBlurFilter.o)
duplicate symbol _kPassthroughFragmentShader in:
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUTransformFilter.o)
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUGaussianBlurFilter.o)
duplicate symbol _kTransformVertexShader in:
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUTransformFilter.o)
/.../CardIO/libCardIO.a(CardIOGPUGaussianBlurFilter.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using XCode 4.6 and card.io SDK version 3.0.10. My linker flags are just -ObjC and -lstdc++

Comment: I'am not sure but it looks like you have two classes that has the same const `nsnotications` in your code. Try to search your code with duplicate symbol without `_` character such as  `kGPUImageGaussianBlurFragmentShaderString`

Comment: I actually tried that before and nothing came up. Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: The fix has been released; I updated my answer below. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. It is a bug; we have a fix and will release a new version soon. I'll update here once it is out.

Update: The fix is out. Please grab the latest version.

Comment: Hello, i get some trouble when use Card.io with another Component that have .mm files, when i add this component Card.io linker issue http://pastebin.com/hvmRqctt